# coc-tsserver is not detecting undefined variables

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol, tsserver

I am using coc and tsserver in my neovim editor, coc-tsserver is providing excellent autocomplete suggestions and warnings as in vs code but it is failing to detect undefined variables. [image]

Can someone help me in configuring this
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install coc-eslint with `:CocInstall coc-eslint` and If you already have an eslint config file in your working directory you are ready to go but make sure you also have eslint npm package installed.

If you don't have the eslint config file you can create one by `:CocCommand eslint.createConfig`